# Devart Error when I return database object with IActionResult

Tags: c#, .net, database, dbcontext, devart

I am trying to return the database object that I get from my service in an IActionResult API Call (c# web API project). Whenever I attempt to do that I get this error:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.
```

Here is my API code that is throwing this:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("content")]
        public IActionResult GetAllContent()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Content> allContent = _contentService.GetAll();
                return Ok(allContent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               //Log something here
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

I could easily mitigate the error by parsing through the content and creating a dynamic object, but I find it annoying to do whenever I want to return a database object when I'm using the Devart Database Context.

Edit:
Further piece of the error message is this:

```
$.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.PortalCodeMappings.Content.ContentId.
```

And I understand the circular reference here, is there a way to tell devart I only want the Content section of this without doing something like this:

```
allContent.Select(x => new { ... });
```

Edit: I am using Devart Entity Devloper to generate my models and the dbcontext. I do not use Visual Studio or any IDE.

Comment: What is the value of `allContent`? The error message seems to have a good explanation of what's going on, do you agree with it?

Comment: Okay good note! let me add some more details to the question, because those extra pieces are important.

Comment: Edit made to the original post @gunr2171

Comment: Try setting Serialize Navigation Properties=None in the properties of the template used in your Devart Entity Model. Does this help in your scenario?

Comment: @Devart I will try that out on Monday when I get back to work. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @Devart I am not seeing any options in Entity Developer for Serialize Navigation Properties. I see several options for Serialize and the option to set it to none or unidirectional, but all those options are off by default.

Comment: You are working with EF Core Model, aren't you? Open your *.efml model, navigate to Tools > Entity Developer > Model Explorer > the Templates node, select the EF Core template, press F4 (Properties), and set Serialize Navigation Properties=None.

Comment: I should add the comment, I am doing all the model and context generation with the Devart Entity Developer tool. I do not use Visual Studio or any IDE for that matter. Are there steps to do all of this within Devart Entity Developer?

Comment: With a standalone Entity Developer tool, navigate to View > Model Explorer > the Templates node, select the EF Core template, press F4 (Properties), and set Serialize Navigation Properties=None. Save the model and press the Generate Code button (F7).

Comment: The only template I have is LinqConnect, am I supposed to have EF Core Template in there?

Comment: If you are working with LinqConnect ORM, your template is LinqConnect (not EF Core). Refer to our answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two alternative ways to solve the issue:

1. Use [System.Text.Json (de)serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references)
2. Add [JsonIgnoreAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute) to one of the navigation property ends

You can add a custom attribute via the interface of Entity Developer this way:

a) navigate to Model > Settings > Attributes > select the System.Text.Json.dll assembly and make sure that JsonIgnoreAttribute is checked in the window below, press OK

b) select JsonIgnoreAttribute in the Attributes collection of a particular class property